# Select tag rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu, view, controller

I have a view where I need to show a list of pages (I have a model called Page) and then i need the id of the selected page

I have this code in the view

## مهمة جديدة

```
: <%= form_for :task, :url => {:action=>"create", :controller=>"tasks"}, :html => {:class :  

=> "nifty_form"} do |f| %>

 <% if @task.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>: عذرا لم نستطع استكمال طلبك</h2>

      <ul>
        <% @task.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li style="color:red;"><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "اسم المهمة" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "وصف المهمة" %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <button><%= link_to 'العودة الى قائمة المهام', project_tasks_path %></button>
    <%= f.submit "مهمة جديدة"%>
  </div>
<%= select_tag(:page, options_for_select(['a',1])) %>
<% end %>
```

`@pageslist` is a 2d array of the form `[['pagename', 1], ..]`

The question is how can i access the page_id of the selected page in the controller ?

I tried `params[:p_id]` but it is not working any help please?

This is what I have in the controller:

```
@task = Project.find(params[:project_id]).tasks.new(params[:task])

@task.update_attributes({:page_id => params[:p_id]})
```

Comment: Can you paste the relevant code chunk in the view?

Comment: You're generating the select tag properly.  Where are you trying to access the page id?  Is it perhaps deeper in the params hash, under a `:page` key?  More context would be helpful.

Comment: I am new to this but I think is that the :p_id gets added to the params hash automatically with the value of the selected page, is that true? I am trying to access the :p_id in the controller using params[:p_id]

Comment: When you submit the form you should see the parameters being sent in the log - what are they?

Comment: Right but you then have to click somewhere and *then* you'd see it in the params hash.  It may be nested if you have a `form_for` call further up.  Put more code in your question and it'll become clearer.

Comment: I edited the post please take a look and thanks for helping :D

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `@pagelist` is in a format as you described, then in your view:

```
<%= select_tag(:page, options_for_select( @pagelist )) %>
```

You had missed it in your example, and provided only 1d array for `options_for_select`.

With such prepared view your `create` action will receive `page id` in:

```
params[:page]
```

it's because you had passed `:page` as a first argument for `select_tag`.